# Passing byte array to PixelShaderEffect

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

I am animating images quickly from a file based on a nonstandard pixel format in a C#/UWP/Win2D application. There is correlation between the images (think flipbook animation) but nothing programmatic.

I have written a prototype and included the relevant code below. The "White" and 
"Black" colors will eventually be converted to a lookup table of colors (e.g. 5 = White)

```
....
//Create render target in function elsewhere
CanvasRenderTarget crt = new CanvasRenderTarget(Sender, FrameWidth, FrameHeight, defaultDpi);
GenerateNextFrame(crt);
....

private void GenerateNextFrame(CanvasRenderTarget frame)
{
    var frameSize = FrameHeight * FrameWidth * sizeof(ushort);
    var frameBytes = new byte[frameSize];
    var frameShorts = new ushort[FrameWidth * FrameHeight];
    var colors = new Color[FrameWidth * FrameHeight];
    var white = Colors.White;
    var black = Colors.Black;
    var comp = (ushort.MaxValue / 2);

    //read bytes from file
    FrameFileStream.AsStreamForRead().Read(frameBytes, 0, frameSize);
    //convert bytes to shorts
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(frameBytes, 0, frameShorts, 0, frameSize);

    //convert shorts to colors
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)
    {
        colors[i] = (frameShorts[i] < comp) ? white : black;
    }
    //set colors on frame
    frame.SetPixelColors(colors);
}
```

The performance is a fine ~60FPS with a FrameWidth/FrameHeight of 512, but drops to ~30FPS at 1024. Anything larger than that performs even worse.

Profiling this with large data shows that the loop over color array and the SetPixelColors calls are the bottlenecks.

I have tried several methods to speed this up (PLINQ, Parallel.ForEach, pre queuing of data) but have failed to get it faster than the form found above.

I believe that the correct way to handle this is to create a new supported type of DirectXPixelFormat for CanvasRenderTarget so that I can just use SetPixelBytes. That appears to be impossible.

The next correct option seems be writing a PixelShaderEffect that accepts frameBytes, create the pixels in greyscale, and then use that as the source of another effect to set the color.

I have not been able to find any examples of creating an IGraphicsEffectSource.

Any advice, documentation, or best of all, a working "this is how you pass a byte array into a PixelShaderEffect" would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with `SetPixelBytes` ? A rough guess is that `SetPixelColors` has to convert colors to bytes, incurring a bit more overhead.

Comment: Also, does the performance suffer when using the default pixel format ? Using a custom format, it might be implicitly converted to another format.

Comment: SetPixelBytes does not work (as written above) because of the nonstandard format. When the data is converted to the default pixel format, the performance is better but not by much. The file read takes longer (data is twice the size) but SetPixelBytes appears to be somewhat faster than the SetPixelColors.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it, I think this is a higher level overall issue, indeed it's bad to read from a file at each frame. You should edit your question to explain the whole thing (input to output), and also a complete example.

Comment: No worries. I appreciate all of your responses. What is missing from the above code? I have left out the basic file I/O and the args.DrawingSession.DrawImage(currentFrame) line. Do you mean a compile-able example? I will edit to add more description/input at your suggestion

Comment: I mean by that a code sample that one could copy/paste and run on his side, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve